# How make a submit php that will send image (from user upload) via email?

Tags: php, image, send, mailer

I need help generating form to email, i'll try many outhere but no one matched i need. I have a form i've got from Bell Online Mailer, but this script doesnt allow image to send... So i modif a little form code and now i already had an upload form. And now what kind of function or php i mustly add to display it as an image (NOT ATTACHED) corectly inside the form message..
here is the code

```
        <?php
    /* 
        BELLonline PHP MAILER SCRIPT v1.5
        Copyright 2006 Gavin Bell 
        http://www.bellonline.co.uk 
        gavin@bellonline.co.uk

        Set up an email form on your website within minutes - see readme.txt for installation.
    */

    extract($_POST);

    if (!file_exists("config.php")) 
        {
    $host = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST ];

$path = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); $file_path = $path['dirname']; print "<h1>BELLonline PHP mailer script</h1>     <h2>There is a problem with your PHP mailer script installation</h2>    <p>The config.php file seems to be missing!</p>     <p>For this script to work, you need to upload the config.php file that came with the download of the BELLonline <a href=\"http://bellonline.co.uk/downloads/php-mailer-script/\">PHP mailer script</a>.</p>    <p>The file must be in the following directory of your website:</p>     <p>$host<span style=\"font-weight: bold; font-size: 150%;\">$file_path/</span></p>  <p>If you need help installing the script, then feel free to email me at <a href=\"&#x6d;&#x61;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#x6f;&#58;&#x67;&#x61;&#118;&#x69;&#110;&#64;&#98;&#x65;&#x6c;&#x6c;&#x6f;&#110;&#x6c;&#105;&#110;&#101;&#46;&#x63;&#111;&#46;&#x75;&#x6b;\">&#x67;&#x61;&#118;&#x69;&#110;&#64;&#98;&#x65;&#x6c;&#x6c;&#x6f;&#110;&#x6c;&#105;&#110;&#101;&#46;&#x63;&#111;&#46;&#x75;&#x6b;</a></p>"; exit;     } include "config.php";


if ($sendto_email == "changeme@example.com")    { print "<h1>BELLonline PHP mailer script</h1>  <h2>Installation nearly complete!</h2>  <p>Thank you for downloading the <a href=\"http://bellonline.co.uk/downloads/php-mailer-script/\" title=\"free PHP mailer script\">free PHP mailer script</a> from <a href=\"http://www.bellonline.co.uk\">BELLonline web services</a>. </p>    <p>To start using the script, open config.php in a text editor and change the <b>&#36;sendto_email</b> variable to your email address.</p>  <p>If you did not get a config.php file with this script, then go to the <a href=\"http://bellonline.co.uk/downloads/php-mailer-script/\">PHP mailer script page</a> and download the full script.</p>  <p>If you need help installing the script, then feel free to email me at <a href=\"&#x6d;&#x61;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#x6f;&#58;&#x67;&#x61;&#118;&#x69;&#110;&#64;&#98;&#x65;&#x6c;&#x6c;&#x6f;&#110;&#x6c;&#105;&#110;&#101;&#46;&#x63;&#111;&#46;&#x75;&#x6b;\">&#x67;&#x61;&#118;&#x69;&#110;&#64;&#98;&#x65;&#x6c;&#x6c;&#x6f;&#110;&#x6c;&#105;&#110;&#101;&#46;&#x63;&#111;&#46;&#x75;&#x6b;</a></p>"; exit;     }  if (empty ($senders_name))   {   $error = "1";   $info_error .= $lang_noname . "<br>";   } if (empty ($senders_email))   {   $error
= "1";  $info_error .= $lang_noemail . "<br>";      } if (empty ($mail_subject))    {   $error = "1";   $info_error .= $lang_nosubject . "<br>";    } if (empty ($mail_message))    {   $error = "1";   $info_error .= $lang_nomessage . "<br>";    } if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", $senders_email))  {   $error = "1";   $info_error .= $lang_invalidemail . "<br>";     } if (empty ($security_code))       {   $error = "1";   $info_error .= $lang_nocode . "<br>";       } elseif ($security_code != $randomness)    {   $error = "1";   $info_error .= $lang_wrongcode . "<br>";    } if ($showlink != "no")    {   $link = "<br><span style=\"font-size: 10px;\">Powered by <a href=\"http://bellonline.co.uk/downloads/php-mailer-script/\" title=\"free PHP mailer script\">BELLonline PHP mailer script</a></span>";    } if ($error == "1")    {   $info_notice = "<span style=\"color: " . $error_colour . "; font-weight: bold;\">" . $lang_error . "</span><br>";       if (empty ($submit))        {       $info_error = "";       $info_notice = $lang_notice;        }   

    function Random()       {       $chars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWZYZ23456789";        srand((double)microtime()*1000000);         $i = 0;         $pass = '' ;        while ($i <= 4)             {           $num = rand() % 32;             $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);             $pass = $pass . $tmp;           $i++;           }       return $pass;       }   $random_code = Random();    $mail_message = stripslashes($mail_message);

    print "<form name=\"BELLonline_email\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\" style=\"margin: 0;\" action=\"\">   <table  border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"2\">
    <tr align=\"$title_align\" valign=\"top\">
      <td colspan=\"2\"><span style=\"$title_css\">$lang_title</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">
      <td colspan=\"2\">$info_notice$info_error</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=\"top\">
      <td align=\"right\">$lang_name</td>
      <td align=\"left\"><input name=\"senders_name\" type=\"text\" class=\"mailform_input\" id=\"senders_name\" style=\"width: $input_width;\" value=\"$senders_name\" maxlength=\"32\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=\"top\">
      <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">$lang_youremail</td>
      <td align=\"left\"><input name=\"senders_email\" type=\"text\" class=\"mailform_input\" id=\"senders_email\" style=\"width: $input_width;\" value=\"$senders_email\" maxlength=\"64\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=\"top\">
      <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">$lang_subject</td>
      <td align=\"left\"><input name=\"mail_subject\" type=\"text\" class=\"mailform_input\" id=\"mail_subject\" style=\"width: $input_width;\" value=\"$mail_subject\" maxlength=\"64\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=\"top\">
      <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">$lang_message</td>
      <td align=\"left\"><textarea name=\"mail_message\" cols=\"36\" rows=\"5\" style=\"width: $input_width;\" class=\"mailform_input\">$mail_message</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=\"top\">
      <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">$lang_image</td>
      <td align=\"left\"><input name=\"mail_image\" size=\"10\" type=\"file\" class=\"mailform_input\" id=\"mail_image\" value=\"$mail_image\" maxlength=\"64\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">
      <td width=\"100\">$lang_confirmation</td>
      <td><input name=\"security_code\" type=\"text\" id=\"security_code\" size=\"5\"> 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>$random_code</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=\"top\">
      <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"right\"><input name=\"randomness\" type=\"hidden\" id=\"randomness\" value=\"$random_code\">
      <input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" value=\"$lang_submit\" class=\"mailform_button\"></td>
    </tr>   </table> </form>";  } else  {

            if ($checkdomain == "yes")          {       $sender_domain = substr($senders_email, (strpos($senders_email, '@')) +1);      $recipient_domain = substr($sendto_email, (strpos($sendto_email, '@')) +1);         if ($sender_domain == $recipient_domain)            {           print "Sorry, you cannot send messages from this domain ($sender_domain)";          exit;           }               }

            $info_notice = $lang_sent;  $mail_message = stripslashes($mail_message);    $mail_image = $_POST['mail_image'];     $content = $mail_image . $mail_message .    '<p> Oleh ' . $senders_name . ', hubungi ' . $senders_email . ' </p>';  $senders_email = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9s.@-_]/", "-", $senders_email);  $from = $senders_email;     $senders_name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9s]/", " ", $senders_name);    $headers = "From: $senders_name <$senders_email> \r\n";     $headers .= "X-Mailer: BELLonline.co.uk PHP mailer \r\n";   $result = sendmail($sendto_email, $mail_subject, $content, $from);


    print "  <table  border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"2\">
    <tr align=\"$title_align\" valign=\"top\">
      <td colspan=\"2\"><span style=\"$title_css\">$lang_title</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align=\"$title_align\" valign=\"top\">
      <td colspan=\"2\">$info_notice</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=\"top\">
      <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">$lang_name</td>
      <td align=\"left\"><b>$senders_name</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=\"top\">
      <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">$lang_youremail</td>
      <td align=\"left\"><b>$senders_email</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign=\"top\">
      <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">$lang_subject</td>
      <td align=\"left\"><b>$mail_subject</b></td>
    </tr>


      <tr valign=\"top\">
          <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">$lang_message</td>
          <td align=\"left\"><b>$mail_message</b></td>
        </tr>
      </table>";
        }

    //Simple mail function with HTML header
    function sendmail($sendto_email, $mail_subject, $content, $from) {
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

        $result = mail($sendto_email, $mail_subject, $content, $headers);

        if ($result) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverflow!** I suspect that there is too much badly formatted code here for most of us to come up with a concise answer that you'll actually find useful.  For "search these 200 lines of code for my bug" problems, you'll get further narrowing things down to just the specific task you're having trouble with.  Want to generate MIME multipart email?  There are lots of Q's about that.  Want to convert a file to base64?  Same with that.  Save an uploaded image to a path that can be referenced in an email?  Lots of documentation on that.  Show us the problem you're having.

Comment: i was a beginner of php, i dont know what to do and just try to copy paste from outsource...
those code you see above was generated by BELL Online mailer not me... I dont suspect that's bad code

Comment: i think that format was simple,

Comment: I didn't say it was "bad code" (which it may be), only that it's badly formatted.  That makes it hard to read, especially in large chunks.  As for your question, remember that StackOverflow is here to help you gain better understanding of your code so that you can write better programs.  It's *not* just a place to get others to do your work for free (though that often happens anyway).  My suggestion: figure out what the Bell mailer does, then write your own mailer with the extra functions you want.  And if something breaks, isolate what's broken and post minimal code to show the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve it using PHP upload or an image uploader (I'm using [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com) at the moment) and [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) to send the email. As you mentioned not to intend sending the image as an attachment, in PHP Mailer, you just have to set an html message with the image inside it.

Comment: Hi Robyflc could you give directly the code you use to process and emailed the image

Comment: I've done it in the past but, unfortunately, I don't have any code that does such things 'in hands'.
I read above that you're a beginner in PHP programming and the tools I suggested have pretty good documentantion and are easy to implement. Even being a beginner you'll be able to make it in know time and will learn a lot in the process.